# How do I keep a CSS hover rule applied when the mouse moves to the child element?

Tags: html, css

I have a table that when you hover each row a delete button slides out from under the last cell in the row. The problem is when I move off of the row to click on the delete button the delete button slides back under the cell because the :hover rule is no longer being applied.

Here is my code:

```css
table {
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

body { font-family: helvetica; }

p {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 200px;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  position: relative;
}

.delete {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  background-color: hsl(0,70%,50%);
  border-radius: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

tr:hover .delete {
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<p>hover the rows</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Test Data</td>
    <td>More Data<div class="delete"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>More Data</td>
    <td>Test Data<div class="delete"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: because your hover is only applied to the `.delete` element. You'd have to hover on the `tr` itself.

Comment: `tr:hover .delete` .... @MarcB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dummy-cell for the delete-button and hide with `left: 0%`, `margin-left:-20px;` and  `overflow: hidden` on the dummy-cell:

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2rr84aaa/)

```
<tr>
    <td>Test Data</td>
    <td>More Data</td>
      <td class="dummy"><div class="delete"></div></td>
  </tr>

.dummy {
    width: 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: none;
}

.delete {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  background-color: hsl(0,70%,50%);
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are losing your hover on the `div` is because of the negative `z-index`.

All you have to do, is to also change the `z-index` along with the `margin` on `:hover`. That's it. no other changes required. Although, you might want to increase the size of the `.delete` a little to be able to capture it within the height of the `tr`.

***Snippet:***

```css
table {
    margin: 10px auto;
    background-color: white; border-collapse: collapse;
}

body { font-family: helvetica; }
p { margin: 10px auto; width: 200px; }

td {
    padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #333; position: relative;
}

.delete {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 100%; width: 20px; height: 20px;
    margin-top: -10px; margin-left: -20px;
    background-color: hsl(0,70%,50%);
    border-radius: 20px; z-index: -1;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

tr:hover .delete {
    margin-left: 2px;
    z-index: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>hover the rows</p>
<table>
 <tr><td>Test Data</td><td>More Data<div class="delete"></div></td></tr>
 <tr><td>More Data</td><td>Test Data<div class="delete"></div></td></tr>
</table>
```